# Huge PHP file script

Tags: php

I have PHP script (machine generated), that has size of 3MB. Its content is mainly couple of `switches` and `echo`. It is not doint anything, only `echos`.
I am using it as "cache" for slow SQL queries, so I generate all possible outputs to this PHP and then use ID in URL to get appropriate result.

So far I have been using script that has 700KB and all was OK. Now, I added some data and I ended up with 3MB. Is it OK to run this or should I consider some other solution ?

Comment: Instead of `echo`, escape out of the interpreter with `?>` for the raw text.

Comment: I have 1 echo / 1 script call.

Comment: It sounds like your time would be better spent optimizing your queries/database rather than propergating this idea any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're rolling your own wonky wheel. Consider using a widely accepted caching solution like [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) or [memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php).

Also consider using the [Zend caching component](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.cache.html) which can be extracted and used in isolation from the rest of the framework and provides an abstracted API for many caching back ends including file based, APC and memcache.

The solution you've described will probably use excessive memory for every execution, waste CPU parsing unnecessary PHP code and make it difficult to handle things like invalidations.

Comment: I have memcached installed, so problem is over

Answer (score 1):

Use a **caching library** rather than pack things into a machine-generated PHP file, because a PHP file of that size still has to be interpreted each time you call it, dragging the hosting server performance down.

One popular caching component out there is https://github.com/illuminate/cache - used in Laravel. You should be able to use it outside of the framework for your program.

And, if you feel more comfortable with it, you can roll your own. Not sure what logic you use to cache queries (where it's literal, simple or complex), but an easy way to correlate weird strings with filenames is through `md5()`:

```
function get_query( $sql ) {
    $cache_filename = sprintf( "cache/%s.sql", md5($sql) );

    if( file_exists($cache_filename) ) {
        return( file_get_contents($cache_filename) );
    }

    // otherwise, perform the query
    $data = ...
    file_put_contents( $cache_filename, $data );

    return( $data );
}
```

The filenames will all look like MD5 hashes. For example, if your query is `"show tables"` the filename will be `cache/489b4ceb2f4301a7132628303f99240d.sql`

Comment: Second solution with generated files looks good. Wouldnt be problem that there will be +- 7000 files in cache dir ?

Comment: Well, this is a bandaid.Your real problem should be optimizing the queries.  But, here you have to pick a lesser of two evils: your overall setup will either have 7,000 files in the cache dir, or one PHP file that's 3 megabytes in size.  In either case, garbage collection is something you should consider separately in your solution. At the very least, with files you know when they were created and can delete the oldest ones.  Incidentally, what type of queries are these that have so much variety and need so much caching?

Comment: I am combining data retrieval from maps, doing some projection calculations in query to select correct data. I have 600,000 entries in DB and I have to operate on the whole set, because I sort depending on SQL user function result.    So far I am using solution with PHP file and its working fine, but now I have increase size of data 5x and I am considered about script size in my solution.

Comment: Gotcha. So I'm not sure (1) what the nature of your data is and (2) how reusable your queries are per-user to decide whether your caching solution is efficient/sufficient, but my hunch is that you should be focusing on moving that DB to something that's faster, better, and native to geodetic data (ex: mysql's spatial extensions).  Ideally you'd not have to cache anything.  If possible, restructure the DB to use quadtrees so there is no lookup needed.

Comment: I know that there are special DB, but for now I am OK. Queries are cachable and it runs 1 / hour and took about 3min. Only problem for now is caching system :)